# Kernel boot error-symfony netbeans

Tags: symfony, netbeans, doctrine-orm, doctrine, phpunit

I have the following code and I just need to test my controller and it takes a request as parameter. But keep getting

> Warning: Deprecated JSON test listener used

and

> PayrollperiodControllerTest::testPayrollWeekCreateAction
>   Error: Call to undefined method PayrollperiodControllerTest::bootKernel()

```
class PayrollperiodControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */

    public function setUp() 
    {   
        self::bootKernel();
        $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
             ->get('doctrine')
             ->getManager();
      }


      public function testPayrollWeekCreateAction(Request $request) {
        $request = Request::create('http://localhost:8000/web/app_dev.php/payrollperiod/new', 'GET');
        $result=$this->em->handle($request);

        $this->assertTrue($result->isSuccessful);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */

    public function tearDown() {
        parent::tearDown();

        $this->em->close();
        $this->em = null; //avoid memory Leaks
    }



}
```

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: an entitymanager can't handle a request (don't have a method handle) probably a typo?

Comment: @Matteo what's a method handle? I used the enitiy manager in the controller , I'm new to this so please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You should extend the KernelTestCase instead of PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase, so try this:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
...
class PayrollperiodControllerTest extends  KernelTestCase {
```

instead of this:

```
class PayrollperiodControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
```

Hope this help

Comment: I tried that but then I'm getting an error about the kerneltestcase and the test screen won't even show.